# rm -fr not working

Tags: files, directory, rm

I have a directory that was generated by mistake by an application and this directory has a structure that involves more than 2000 directories, one inside a another, something like:

Directory `aaaa` inside `bob` inside `ccc` inside `ddd` inside `eee` etc. These are 1000 levels deep and many of these directories have names where spaces are URL encoded (spaces are `%20` and `>` are `%3E` etc).

If I try to remove that directory using `rm -fr` I get the message `directory is not empty`. I think the string necessary to remove a directory is too long for UNIX. Is there a way to delete this directory with `rm`?

I am on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Comment: What is the output of `type -a rm`?

Comment: rm is /bin/rm ... why?

Comment: Can you remove it in the finder?

Comment: /bin is the correct location for rm since /sbin is usually reserved for privileged commands that are to be run only by root, wheel, or admins.  If rm was in /sbin, how would normal users delete their files?  For the same reason, basic commands like cp, mv, and ls are in /bin and not /sbin.

Comment: Try using:
sudo rm -rfv /path/to/file
Perhaps it is a permission issue with one of the nested files and sudo will let you get past it, although usually you get an error message if this is the case.  Also the -v will verbosely list the files, so maybe it will show you if it is getting hung up on a certain file.  Can you please post your output starting from the rm command you type all the way until the next prompt that the terminal returns?

Comment: @ott - no, finder is refusing.

Comment: @MichaelYasumoto - no, I did using sudo... same message

Comment: Try using the `find` command instead.  First confirm the syntax using `ls` instead of `rm` to make sure that you get the output you expect, which should be a list of the files you want to delete.  Because of the size of the directory you are dealing with, terminate the command early with `Ctrl+C` and scan the output:
`find -d /path/to/file -exec ls {} \;`
If everything looks good, then swap out the `ls` for `rm -rf` and hopefully the directory will be removed:
`find -d test -exec rm -rf {} \;`

Comment: If you have access to usual open-source utilities, you could also try Midnight Commander.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `rm -rf stuff_to_delete` with a very deep structure then it is possible that there are too many directories for rm to handle.

You can work around this with:

`find /starting/path/to/delete/from -type d -delete`

or with

`find -type d /starting/path/to/delete/from -exec rm -f {} \;`

The first should just work. The second command starts a new command (rm) for each directory, but that allows you to use `rm`'s force flag. I assume it is not needed though and I expect the first command to be faster.

Regardless of command used, try first with -print to make sure your path is correct.

Comment: perfect! The only thing this works is something like your first command. I found this one just seconds before reading your solution and this worked for me ........ find . -name '.*' -delete     THANKS!

Comment: Do you have a reference for "it is possible that there are too many directories for rm to handle"? A recursive rm does the same kind of depth first traversal that "find" does, so I don't see how it could fail unless it ran out of memory to store the directory tree as it traverses it (in which case it should give an out of memory error, not silently fail).

Comment: Just to satisfy my own curiosity, I created a directory tree 10,000 levels deep, with each level having 50 small text files, and rm -r worked just fine. But this was on Linux, does the OSX version of rm have problems with deep directory trees?

Answer (score 0):

I have observed failures of "sudo rm -fr " on my MacOSX 10.8 laptop fairly regularly.  In the latest case, the directory I was deleting contained ~28,000 file in a directory hierarchy that was maybe 8 or 10 levels deep, at most; the total size was about 4 GB on disk. Simply running "sudo rm -fr " a second time removed the leftover files, as it always has for me.

It doesn't look to me like the problem is the depth of the directory hierarchy, because the undeleted files always seem to be near the top of the directory tree.  It's hard to believe it could have anything to do with the total number of files or directories, because I would expect 'rm' to delete these directories recursively.